# Hibernate/JPA Mapping on abstract class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

What would be the best practice to implement the following situation with Hibernate.

We define an abstract class that will form the base of any object that we want to persist in our database. It contains the id etc etc...

```
public abstract class ModelObject {
    protected int id;

    ...
}
```

Now we subclass our base clase for special cases where more than one entity will have a similar fields.

```
public abstract class ModelObjectWithNose extends ModelObject {
    ...
    protected Nose nose;
}
```

Now, for all classes that we want to have a `Nose`:

```
public class Person extends ModelObjectWithNose { ... }

public class Animal extends ModelObjectWithNose { ... }
```

The real problem we have at the moment now is that this relationship needs to be bi-directional. Each concrete class needs to know which `Nose` is theirs, but each `Nose` also needs to know to what object it belongs.

```
public class Nose {
    ...
    private ModelObjectWithNose owner;
}
```

For our example we need a `@OneToOne` relationship, as each `Person` can only have one `Nose` and each `Nose` can only belong to one `Person`.

What we have tried is doing the following:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class ModelObjectWithNose extend ModelObject { ... }
```

and then:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends ModelObjectWithNose { ... }
```

...etc etc etc.

1) How do I define the relationship between the `Nose` and the `ModelObjectWithNose`? Is it as simple as:

```
@Entity
public class Nose {
    ...
    // this causes: 'Basic' attribute should not be 'Persistence Entity' 
    ModelObjectWithNose owner;
}
```

2) Is there a better / more preferred way? Would the inheritance strategy work properly?

Thanks!

***EDIT***

So I have tried a few ways which all seem to potentially work. Using any of the three Inheritance schemes works fine if you set up the annotations as in the question. Unfortunately this has a huge impact on our existing database and code, so we opted to (for now) simply index the `Nose` object's `id` field that is kept on our current objects that would have extended `ModelObjectWithNose` and simply write helper methods to do point queries to find the entries.

Comment: Where are `@OneToOne`s in your mapping?

Comment: @axtavt - So the @OneToOne would be on both `ModelObjectWithNose` in the `Nose` class, and on `Nose` in the `ModelObjectWithNose`. Please see my edit for further details.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on the "huge impact" the various inheritance strategies have on your code? It'd be interesting to read.

Comment: @Tom Anderson - Well, since our code base is quite mature (+-3 years), and the initial design did not take this inheritance into account, stepping towards this would mean a rewrite of most of our `@Entity` classes (of which there are more than 100). Then also, we cannot simply recreate our databases, as numerous clients use it. So we would have to either write SQL to `ALTER` the existing databases to mimic what it should look like, or write an ETL process to do the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your `Nose` property in `ModelObjectWithNose` as `@OneToOne` and in the `Nose` entity you do the same with `ModelObjectWithNose owner`. Set the `mappedBy` attribute of the annotation of the `Nose` entity, so JPA knows on which table the FK should be inserted (In your model the `ModelObjectWithNose` should have the FK to `Nose`, not other way around. You set it on the inverse end of the one-to-one relationship, ie. the one that has the PK to use.)

BTW your Entities must implement `Serializable` (you can do so on the `ModelObject` class to enforce it on inheriting classes). The `id` property of `ModelObject` should be annotated as `@Id`.

Cheers,
Kai

Comment: Thanks. The code above was just skeleton code. Our `ModelObject` does implement `Serializable`. I have also added the `@OneToOne`. As mentioned in one of my comments, we have opted for a different solution since we would have to make too many changes to our existing code. But thanks, your solution would work (I tried it on a small proof-of-concept).